# Strange characters instead of text (”¹±²¬ÃÄµ µ´Î Ä¿)

Tags: excel, facebook, text

I have downloaded Facebook content data of a page which contains both English and Greek posts. However, text in Greek is not displayed in Excel csv file. Any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance!

[Strange Characters-pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21T3a.png)

Comment: Likely a problem of mishandled character encoding somewhere, but your problem description is way too vague right now, to be able to say anything more. Please go read [ask], and then explain what exactly you did.

Comment: It could also be an issue with Excel itself - because that is notoriously bad at correctly recognizing character encoding, when files are opened using double click. Importing the data via the menu, and then manually selecting the correct encoding often helps.

Comment: Not all csv file types are exactly the same. In your case I suspect that you have to convert your csv file to UTF-8 encoding first. When selecting 'Save As' in excel and opening the drop-down menu for selecting the file type, you can actually see that there different options for csv file types, all of which end on .csv once saved though: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3dxP.png)